# Shortcut icon inside a cab file

Tags: deployment, compact-framework, cab

How do I place the shortcut icon in the cab file? Can anyone shed some light on this? I searched online and found no info about this at all, except a claim that the icon used in the smart device project is automatically pulled into a cab. Well, it isn't so. It got pulled in once and after that when i CHANGED the icon it still shows an old one.

Any clues?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shortcut icon is the icon from the application itself, so you don't "add" one.  Bear in mind that WinMo/Pocket PC caches that icon for the Start menu, so if your app had a different icon to begin with, then you'll probably have to soft-reset the device to get the start menu to pick up the new icon.

Comment: by soft reset you mean reboot? it does look like its being cached.

Comment: great, rebooting helped. Thanks!